# Magento 2 Admin Panel is Very Slow

Tags: magento2, admin, session

Right now, my admin panel is very slow. I wait min 15 sec to load every grid. I created new account and logged in with it. There isn't any problem, it loads with 2-3 sec.

What should i do?

Comment: try clearing the cache and rebuilding the static content `bin/magento s:s:d -f`

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear out the ui_bookmark table for your user, there is where config/filters are applied and stored for each user.